# Get minimum diff between elements in each group

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a mysql table in the following form:

- timestamp (unix timestamp)
- some value columns [...]
- groupid

Now I want to build a query which groups by groupid and prints the minimum time difference between each of the timestamps in the group.

Something like SELECT groupid, MIN(??? - ???) as minimum_time_diff FROM mytable GROUP BY groupid;

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: What do you mean the difference between ALL elements?

Answer (score 0):

One way is with a self-join and `group by`:

```
select t1.groupid, min(timestampdiff(second, t1.timestamp, t2.timestamp)) as minsecs
from table t1 join
     table t2
     on t1.groupid = t2.groupid and t1.timestamp < t2.timestamp
group by t1.groupid;
```

You can also do this with variables:

```
select groupid, min(timestampdiff(second, prevtimestamp, timestamp))
from (select t.*,
             if(@groupid = groupid, @prevtimestamp, NULL) as prevtimestamp,
             @prevtimestamp := timestamp,
             @groupid = groupid
      from table t cross join
           (select @prevtimestamp := 0, @groupid = '')
      order by groupid, timestamp
     ) t
group by groupid;
```

This uses the observation that when the timestamps are ordered, then the minimum difference is going to occur between two adjacent rows.